# How to stop typing, when characters is greater than 10?

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

Follow the code:

**Html:**

```
<textarea id="summernote">Test</textarea>
<h5 id="limite_vermelho" style="text-align:right;color:red"></h5>
<h5 id="limite_normal" style="text-align:right"></h5>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#summernote').on('summernote.keyup', function(e) {
    var text = $(this).next('.note-editor').find('.note-editable').text();
    var length = text.length;
    var num = 10 - length;

    if (length > 10) {
        $('#limite_normal').hide();
        $('#limite_vermelho').text(10 - length).show();
    }
    else{
        $('#limite_vermelho').hide();
        $('#limite_normal').text(10 - length).show();
    }    
});
```

Or if you prefer in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/114/

Comment: There isn't a question here, please read [ask].

Comment: Is the title what you want to happen, or is that the problem you are encountering?

Comment: @Konstantinos "whats the problem? jsfiddle works fine..", Does not work. I want to stop typing and not continue typing

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, It's the title.

Comment: Check answer please @MatheusMiranda

Comment: Yeah, Good job @Konstantinos.

Comment: `<textarea maxlength="10">`

Comment: @epascarello maxlength does not work with summernote!

Comment: And I do not know every library out there. I saw a textarea and figured the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/116/
You just need to insert this code:

```
$("#summernote").summernote("code", text.substring(0,10));
```

Comment: Tank you @Konstantinos

Comment: Is it possible to keep text in bold?

Comment: no it will delete the characters, what do you wnat?